# finding out the cause of this segmentation fault 11 in a shortest path C code

Tags: c, xcode

Hello i've been working on a code to simulate shortest path algorithm but i got stuck where i kept getting segmentation fault 11 error here is my code

```
#include <curses.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>


int size = 20;


#define IN 99



char *
strrev (char *str)
{
    if (!str) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() Error: invalid string\n", __func__);
        return NULL;
    }

    char *begin = str;
    char *end = str + strlen (str) - 1;
    char tmp;

    while (end > begin)
    {
        tmp = *end;
        *end-- = *begin;
        *begin++ = tmp;
    }

    return str;
}

int dijsktra(int costMatrix[][size],int source,int target)

{

    int distance[size],previous[size],IsSelected[size],i,m,minimum,s,d,j;
    memset(IsSelected, 0, size*sizeof(IsSelected[0]));
    char pathMatrix[size];

    for(i=1;i<size;i++)

    {

        distance[i] = IN;

        previous[i] = -1;

    }

    s = source;

    IsSelected[s]=1;

    distance[s] = 0;

    while(IsSelected[target] ==0)

    {

        minimum = IN;

        m = 0;

        for(i=1;i<size;i++)

        {

            d = distance[s] +costMatrix[s][i];

            if(d< distance[i]&&IsSelected[i]==0)

            {

                distance[i] = d;

                previous[i] = s;

            }

            if(minimum>distance[i] && IsSelected[i]==0)

            {

                minimum = distance[i];

                m = i;

            }

        }

        s = m;

        IsSelected[s] = 1;

    }

    s = target;

    j = 0;

    while(s != -1)

    {

        pathMatrix[j++] = s+65;

        s = previous[s];

    }

    pathMatrix[j]='\0';

    strrev(pathMatrix);

    printf("%s", pathMatrix);

    return distance[target];

}



int main(int argc, char** argv)

{
    int siz = argc;
    int id, port;
    int N;
    int costMatrix[N][N], i, j, ch, co;
    int *data;
    int startNode, source, target,x,y;

    id = atoi(argv[1]);

    port = atoi(argv[2]);

    N = argc-1;
    data=(int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));


    for (i=1;i<siz;i++)
    {
        data[i]=atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("%d\n",data[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", N);


    printf("\tDIJKSRTRA's ALGORITHM\n\n");


   /* for(i=1;i< N;i++)
        printf("%d ", i);
        for(j=1;j< N;j++)
            printf("%d ", j);
            costMatrix[i][j]=IN;

    for(x=1;x< N;x++)

    {

        for(y=x+1;y< N;y++)

        {

            printf("The weight of the path between router port %d and %d : %d",x,y, atoi(argv[y]));



            costMatrix [x][y] = costMatrix[y][x] = atoi(argv[y]);

        }

        printf("\n");

    }*/
    printf("yo");
    startNode = atoi(argv[2]);
    source = atoi(argv[3]);

    target = atoi(argv[5]);

    co = dijsktra(costMatrix,N,startNode);

    printf("\nShortest Path: %d",co);

}
```

i commented the loop in my main because i assumed it was caused by it but it turns out its not. segmentation fault 11 happens before the printf("yo");. any idea or help would appreciated

Comment: How do you call the program?

Comment: local variables (and function parameters) names should indicate `content` or `usage` ( or better, both)  names like: `m` `s` `d`, etc are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: the posted code is all double spaced. This is not a good style.  Suggest Separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  In general, do not insert spurious blank lines in the code

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2)  insert a reasonable space: inside parens, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: it is a good idea to insert a comment(s) in the code, that explain the objective of parts of the code, so the reader of the code does not have to reverse engineer the code to determine what the code is trying to perform.

Comment: when compiling the code, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra, -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers will use different parameters

Comment: using hard coded integer values for ASCII characters make the code much more difficult to understand.  Regarding: `pathMatrix[j++] = s+65;`  suggest using: `pathMatrix[j++] = s+'A';`

Comment: why have this statement: `#include <math.h>`  twice?  Infact why include that header file at all as none of its' contents are being used.?

Comment: regarding: `char *end = str + strlen (str) - 1; the function `strlen()` returns the index to the NUL byte.  Subtracting 1 means the last 'read' character in the string will not be procased

Comment: what does `dijsktra` mean?

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, 1) the return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc. 2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" );` as that will output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the function failed.

Comment: the posted code fails to check `argc` to assure the desired number of parameters has been supplied on the command line.  And if not the desired number of parameters, the output a `USAGE` message to `stderr`, indicating what parameters (and their type) are expected.  Suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, "%s ....\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding: `data = calloc(size,sizeof(int));`  The function: `calloc()` expects all its' parameters to be of type `size_t` but the variable: `size` is of type `int`

Comment: regarding: `startNode = atoi(argv[2]);
    source = atoi(argv[3]);

    target = atoi(argv[5]);`  the code just collected these in the array `data[]` so why do it again?  just pass the items in the array `data[]`  Or better, just pass `data` and eliminate the extra (duplicate) parameters from the signature of function: `dijsktra`

Comment: the posted code contains several `#include`  statements.  However, the include of `curses.h` and `math.h` (both occurrences ) should be removed as it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used

Comment: there are several local variable defined which are either never used or set then never read.  Suggest removing those variables

Comment: @user3629249 dijsktra is obviously a misspelling of dijkstra.

Comment: [Dijkstra algorithm](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2014/03/dijkstra-algorithm-for-finding-shortest-path-of-a-graph.html) looks nothing like the OPs posted code.  BTW: this example took only a couple of minutes to find, using `google` and searching for: `example of dijkstra algorithm in c`